# Fetch content in AWS S3 public bucket from GCP Data Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to fetch the content of the bucket `s3://open-images-dataset` from GCP data storage through the `gsutil` or the transfer service. I am using the following command in the case of the command line alternative:

`gsutil -m -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp -r --no-sign-request s3://open-images-dataset gs://<bucket-name>`

The problem here is that the `s3://open-images-dataset` is public and one would usually do `--no-sign-request` when downloading it to a local directory. However as far as I have been able to see GCP don't allow any option to go over this issue. Any idea about that problem?

I can not download it first to my local machine because the content of the bucket is too big.

Answer (score 0):

gsutil uses [the Boto library](https://github.com/boto/boto) to handle communicating with S3. After a bit of digging through the code, it seems Boto allows specifying that [an individual connection should be anonymous](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/8fac1878734c5ac085b781f619c70ea4b6e913c3/boto/s3/connection.py#L174)... but it looks it would require patching the Boto library to make all S3 connections for a given session be anonymous (i.e. setting a Boto config option like "no_sign_request = True" under the [s3] section).

When I try to list that bucket with AWS credentials set, via `gsutil ls s3://open-images-dataset`, the signed request succeeds.  Given that it works, is there any particular reason you don't want the request to be signed?

**Edit**

I submitted this pull request to add support for `no_sign_request` in Boto:

https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3833

It will be in the next version of Boto, whenever they decide to release it. At that point, gsutil can grab the new version and include it in a subsequent release.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly fine after setting AWS credentials.
In my case, I was trying to avoid the part of the process of needing to request those from AWS. Before requesting the credentials, when I try the solution the output is the following one:
ERROR 0915 11:05:35.895289 utils.py] Unable to read instance data, giving up
Failure: No handler was ready to authenticate. 4 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler', 'DevshellAuth', 'OAuth2Auth', 'OAuth2ServiceAccountAuth'] Check your credentials.
However, your proposal is a really good workaround I really appreciate it!

Comment: Makes sense.  I submitted a PR to Boto on GitHub to add the functionality I mentioned in my answer: https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3833

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible at the moment but a [PR](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3833) has been issued to the boto library.